# If/when with checkboxes in Access?

Tags: ms-access

Ok here's what I need help with in Access...

Check boxes 1-5 are prerequisites for jobs listed like degree, years of experience etc.

In check boxes 8-10 are the available jobs

When reviewing someone's resume, we would check any boxes between 1-5 based on their skills. Boxes 1,3, and 5 are prerequisites for check box 8. Question is how do I auto-populate box 8 to automatically check if boxes 1, 3, and 5 are checked?

Should I use the IIF function in the Control Source of box 8 or generate a query? What is a good example of the code that needs to be written? Thanks so much!

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: checkboxes are named chk1-chk10.  Add an AfterUpdate event on each check 1,3,5 and add a procedure to run the automatic update of chk8.

```
Private Sub chk1_AfterUpdate()
UpdateChk8
End Sub

Private Sub chk3_AfterUpdate()
UpdateChk8
End Sub

Private Sub chk5_AfterUpdate()
UpdateChk8
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateChk8()
If Me.chk1 = True And Me.chk3 = True And Me.chk5 = True Then
    Me.chk8 = True
Else
    Me.chk8 = False
End If
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I got it working but I have another question.  Boxes 1-6 apply to box 8 but what if boxes 2-7 applies to box 9?  Do you need to add to the second line(UpdateChk8) to make it say `UpdateChk8 , UpdateChk9`?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TNguyen, you'd need to create a separate procedure that validates the checks in 2-7.  Then on the AfterUpdate events for each of the applicable checkboxes you'd add a reference to that new procedure.  You can call as many procedures as you'd like, but don't separate them with commas, just enter the new procedure name on a new line.

Comment: I literally figured it out right when you posted the reply!  I'm a bit of a noob to vb(as you can tell).  Do you recommend any tutorial videos for me to watch?  Thanks again!